# Keyboard resizable frameset

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

Is there any way to resize a `frameset` or frameset-like elements, e.g. [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/Bek9L/), using keyboard? Isn't it a usability issue if you can't resize them without a mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the top of my head, I would say that a frame border is not a 'focusable' element (unlike e.g. input elements) so you can't 'tab' to it, by design.

So yes, you'll need a mouse **unless** you write some js / jQuery or use e.g. [mouse trap](http://craig.is/killing/mice) or the likes to bind keys to some resizing animation or proportion manipulation.